# How to repeatedly call an API every x seconds to update coordinates?

Tags: python

I have an app that calls an API for coordinates and pushes the coordinates to a map. I want to call the API every 15 seconds to update the coordinates of the map. I am having trouble understanding how to repeatedly call the API at an interval to update the map:

```
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
#Create function for getting API JSON
def get_API():
    iss_data = requests.get("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
    response = iss_data.json()
    s.enter(15,1, get_API)
    return response

json_response = get_API()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_response, orient="index")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ‘while’ loop to keep the program running  https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

and then use the time module to sleep for 15 or whatever seconds
https://realpython.com/python-sleep/

Comment: If every 15 seconds is critical, sleep(15) won't work as intended due to the time taken to run the code

Comment: Yep hence what ever seconds. 
If it is super important then will have to do a date time before running the query then a date time afterwards. Do a delta and sleep that long

Comment: if you don't want cumulative error in your polling time, just do, for example, 1 second sleeps and after each sleep, check the actual elapsed time from last poll with `time.time()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using a combination of a [`thread.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object to call the API function and a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) object to signal when the call has occurred. The latter is basically a flag that can be safely set, cleared, and checked by other threads in a multithreaded program.

One limitation with this approach is that the results of the API call can't be returned directly, so a wrapper function will need to be used to make the actual call to the API do something with the results. In the example below, the results of the API call are simply printed in the wrapper. Note that the wrapper function can be passed an arbitrary sequence of arguments — which might be useful, for instance, if you wanted to store the data somewhere or have some sort of callback function called whenever new data was retrieved.

```
import json
import requests
import threading

DELAY = 15.0  # Time between calls in seconds.

def call_API(event):
    iss_data = requests.get("https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544")
    response = iss_data.json()
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))  # Do something with results...
    event.set()  # Signal call has been made.

print('Running')
event = threading.Event()
while True:
    event.clear()
    timer = threading.Timer(DELAY, call_API, (event,))  # Call after delay.
    timer.start()
    event.wait()  # Blocks until event is set by another thread.
```

Comment: ogplant: Does this help?